# Hibernate - automatically assign foreign key to child?

Tags: hibernate, composite-key

Ok, so I have 2 objects, Parent and Child. The child basically looks like this:

```
public class Child implements Serializable 
{

    // primary (composite) key
    private int parentId;
    private String name;

    // random value
    private String val;

    public Child(String name, String val) {
        this.name = name;
        this.val = val;
        // note: parentId is not assigned a value
    }

    public void setParentId(int id) {

    [...]
}
```

What I want is basically for hibernate to automatically set the parent id of the Child once a Parent object is created. Is this possible or do I have to add child objects to the parent object after the parent object has been saved to the database?

The xml mapping of the parent looks as such:

```
`<map name="children" inverse="true" lazy="true" cascade="all,delete-orphan">
    <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write"/>
    <key column="parent_id"/>
    <index column="child_name" type="string"/>
    <one-to-many class="myPack.Child"/>
</map>`
```

and the xml of the child:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="myPack">

    <class name="Child" table="child_tbl" lazy="true">

        <composite-id>
            <key-property name="ParentId" type="int" column="parent_id"/>
            <key-property name="Name" column="name" type="string"/>
        </composite-id>

        <property name="Val" blablabla
[...]
```

Comment: So was your problem solved?I don't see any answer accepted nor any comments.

Comment: What I ended up doing was to loop through all children in the DAO upon saving the Parent object and setting their parent reference. Not what I originally wanted to do but it works just as well I guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want hibernate to insert parent-child together with a foreign key use object mapping rather than ids.

Lets take an example from [here](http://jyops.blogspot.com/2011/03/hibernate-mapping-example.html),

```
public class AMain {
 
 //Properties of A.
 List<ASub3> subList;
.....
}

public class ASub3 {
 .....  
 AMain parent;
 .....
}
```

in the hbm.xml file in AMain add,

```
    <list name="subList" inverse="true" cascade="all" lazy="false">
         <key column="a_id" />
         <list-index column="as3_id" />
         <one-to-many class="com.manu.hibernate.mappings.domain.ASub3" />
    </list>
```

in Asub3 add,

```
<many-to-one name="parent" class="com.manu.hibernate.mappings.domain.AMain" 
column="a_id" unique="true" cascade="save-update" />
```

Now, in the client code use the beans as below,

```
     AMain a = new AMain("A");
     ASub3 as3a = new ASub3("List - 1");
     ASub3 as3b = new ASub3("List - 2");
     ASub3 as3c = new ASub3("List - 3");
     as3a.setParent(a);
     as3b.setParent(a);
     as3c.setParent(a);
     List<ASub3> subList = new ArrayList<ASub3>();
     subList.add(as3a);
     subList.add(as3b);
     subList.add(as3c);

     a.setSubList(subList);
```

Now, if youn save AMain both AMain and ASub3 will be updated(I mean corresponding table) with a foreign key to AMain.

Answer (score -1):

Hi Days before i was also facing same problem. I have solution in Annotation Classes. As I do not have your parent class let me go with my assumption

```
public class Parent implements Serializable 
{
   // Id is generated by sequence so it is not assigned when parent will be created
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_APP")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_APP",sequenceName="SEQ_APP")
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "CHILD_TABLE",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")},  
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "NAME")}
    )
    @Cascade(CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
   private Set<Child> childs= new HashSet<Child>();

   // getters and setters
}



public class Child {
       // primary (composite) key

       private int parentId;
       private String name;    }
```

Comment: this is not xml mapping